# C++ static variables not giving the correct output

Tags: c++, static

I don't seem to get how the answer is b and not d. I know it has to do something with the variable b being declared as a static variable. But what exactly is going on with the variables? Thanks in advance.

Consider the following code:

```
 class Numbers { 
   private: 
      int a;
      static int b;

    public:
      Numbers(int x) : a(x) { b = x; } 
      void incA() { a++; } 
      void incB() { b++; } 
      int getA() { return a; } 
      int getB() { return b; }
  }; 

  int main() { 
    Numbers n1(1); 
    Numbers n2(2); 
    n1.incA(); 
    n1.incB(); 
    n2.incA(); 
    n2.incB();
    cout << n1.getA() << "," << n1.getB() << endl; 
    return 0;
  }
```

What is the output from the above program?
(a) 2,2 (b) 2,4 (c) 2,5 (d) 2,3

Comment: Is this an exam or interview question? It's not something you can try out and debug? And the program as shown won't even build so *all* the answers are wrong.

Comment: A static variable is shared amongst class objects. Read through the code again with that in mind.

Answer (score -2):

Answer is b: 2,4

`static int b` is shared across multiple 'Numbers' objects.

You also need to define it in one of the source files like following:
`int Numbers::b;`